# Same Query But ORDER BY Producing Different Results

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, collation

I am running two MySQL servers (production and test).  I run the same query on both via MySQL Workbench, but the results are not in the same order.  What is the reason?

The query:

```
select table_name, table_collation 
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = 'orchestration' 
order by table_name asc`
```

[image: Here's the actual output]

Comment: Are the production and test instances of MySQL running the same version?

Comment: Bill Karwin, test version is 8.0.11; production is 5.6.33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> test version is 8.0.11; production is 5.6.33

MySQL 8.0 completely changes the internal implementation of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA. See https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-improvements-to-information_schema/ for the announcement.

I also see that you are using a utf8 collation in test, but utf8mb4 in production, and again, using different versions. MySQL has also made corrections to their collations between versions. Sometimes they had a bug with their older implementation, and sometimes the specification for the collation is updated by some standards committee, and MySQL changes to maintain compatibility with the standard.

Many software packages make changes between major versions, and you shouldn't expect perfect compatibility between them.

You should make sure you are developing, testing, and deploying to production using the same version of all software packages in your technology stack. Databases, languages, frameworks, web servers, cache servers, proxies, load balancers, message queues, libraries, etc. can all introduce subtle changes even if they aren't documented.

You're at risk of being surprised by incompatibilities and bugs if you test on one version but deploy to production on a different version of the technology stack. Effectively, your testing doesn't give any assurance that your code will work in production!

Comment: Hi Bill.  I want to dig deeper, but I hit a roadblock.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE information_schema.TABLES` turns out to be a `VIEW`, but the output is truncated.  Where can I find the schemas for the new 8.0 DD tables?  (And why is the SHOW truncated?)

Comment: I tried on a sandbox instance of 8.0.14, and it seems to be not truncated. I use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` or `SHOW CREATE VIEW` and see it as 4205 characters. Interesting the "views" in information_schema do not themselves show up in `information_schema.views`.

Comment: I used 8.0.15 in docker.  The output did not get as far as to give the `FROM` or `JOIN` to tell me where the underlying tables are.  Can you tell me what they are?  And is it possible to do `SHOW` on them?

Comment: The underlying tables are `mysql.tables`, `mysql.schemata`, `mysql.catalogs`, `mysql.collations`, `mysql.tablespaces`, `mysql.table_stats`. These are internal data dictionary objects, and they are not showable: `ERROR 3554 (HY000): Access to data dictionary table 'mysql.tables' is rejected.` Here's an explanation: https://lefred.be/content/mysql-8-0-data-dictionary-tables-and-why-they-should-stay-protected/

Comment: Thanks, but ugh.  I'll pursue that when I have a spare week.  Even if I could see the 'hidden' tables, it might not explain why `_` seems to collate differently.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your collation is different locally compared to the server? E.g. you launched local with `mysqld --character-set-server=utf8mb4`, or something quite different than the production server?

Also, the underlying operating system may behave differently. I don't recall seeing a specific character set that sorted '_' and 's' differently, but I guess it's possible.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to my original post; does this help?

Comment: Bill Karin's answer above is more on-target; different versions will give you a world of headache (and not just a MySQL issue!). Can you export the test DB, and load into same version in test?

Comment: Looks like that's the direction I'll have to go!

Answer (score 0):

```
select  table_name, table_collation
    from  information_schema.tables
    order by  table_name COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Notes:

- `S` < `_` < `s` -- So if someone is doing `UPPER()` or `LOWER()`, the ordering changes.
- utf8_bin and utf8_general_ci give different answers; perhaps the underlying DD table changed?

(Alas, I was not able to get to the bottom of the issue.)